# Lambda not working even when the condition is satisfied in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I want to print 1 if the word is in the paragraph, if not then print 0

[The first line contains the word bestselling yet lambda is printing 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCg57.png)

Comment: Copy the code here. Don't link/attach images. It would be hard to reproduce them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do that is to use [*any*](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_any.asp) function and cast to int the result.

```py
text = "this is a text used for an example."

first_list = ["word", "second_word", "example"]
second_list = ["word", "second_word", "third_word"]

is_in = int(any(k in text for k in first_list))
print(is_in) # print 1

not_in = int(any(k in text for k in second_list))
print(not_in) # print 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to search in a DataFrame would be using the `contains` method of str (documentation [here)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html). In your case you want to search whether multiple words are in the text, so a regular expression could be used:

```
df["sun"][0].str.contains("brilliant|bestselling|best|best-selling|loved|great|amazing", regex=True)
```

If you also want to match the word regardless of if it's in lowercase or uppercase you can add:

```
import re
df["sun"][0].str.contains("brilliant|bestselling|best|best-selling|loved|great|amazing", flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)
```